# How to calculate years, months and days into datefield

Tags: python, django, date

First of i have this varibale called first_date

```
first_date = models.DateField()
```

I have a method called recurrence which returns 3 ints.

```
 @property
def recurrence(self):
    return '%dY, %dM, %dD' % (self.year_interval, self.month_interval, self.day_interval)
```

Finally i need to make the method which takes the first_date and add the Ints from the recurrence method:

```
@property
def next_date(self):
    return self.first_date + datetime.timedelta(self.recurrence)
```

It dont work, but do any of you guys know how to make it possible if you want to add (1,5,13) then it will add 1 year 5 montsh and 13 days to the first_date?

Comment: `recurrence` doesn't "return three ints", it returns a string containing three integer values. Whenever you are doing arithmetic with dates and times the `datetime` module is worth considering.

Comment: From the question it is not clear to me what you are doing. Are your methods part of your class models.DateField()? If so, what is `self.first_date`? If you provide a complete, minimal code example you might get more responses.

Comment: You can't initialise a `datetime.timedelta` with a string like that. But anyway, month lengths are irregular, and year lengths depend on whether or not they're leap years, so it doesn't make sense to specify a `timedelta` in terms of years &/ or months. However, if you change your logic a little you can probably achieve what you want via the `datetime.datetime.replace` method.